# Wrong version of web3.js

Tags: web3js, nodejs

```
$ npm show web3

web3@1.2.5-rc.0 | LGPL-3.0 | deps: 8 | versions: 115
Ethereum JavaScript API
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js#readme
...
```

```
$ node app/test.js 
VERSION { api: '0.18.4',
  node: [Getter],
  getNode: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  network: [Getter],
  getNetwork: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  ethereum: [Getter],
  getEthereum: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  whisper: [Getter],
  getWhisper: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] }
```

Here is `app/test.js`:

```
let web3js = require("web3")

let web3 = new web3js(new web3js.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

console.log("VERSION", web3.version)
```

Why do two different tests (run in the same directory) show two different versions of web3.js: `1.2.5-rc.0` and `0.18.4`?!

Comment: Node allows to have multiple version of the same package. How your package.json looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think,

```
$ npm show web3
```

This command shows the version of web3 globally installed on your system.

```js
let web3js = require("web3")
    
let web3 = new web3js(new web3js.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
    
console.log("VERSION", web3.version)
```

This shows the locally installed version of web3 in your current project.